# Counting records from Category returned in another query with PHP & SQL

Tags: php, sql, database, count, echo

I'm using [AlphaListNav.js](https://elliottprogrammer.github.io/alphaListNav.js/) to create an A-Z of Musicians with a list of their releases.

My SQL table `music`, has fields `id`, `artists`, `year`, `title` and `genre`

I'm returning a list of `artists` from the table using the following code and it works fine.

```
<ul id="myList">

      <?php

          include_once("conn.php");

          $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT artists FROM music ORDER BY ASC";
          $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
          $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

              if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
              {
                 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                 {

      ?>

      <li><?php echo $row["artists"];?>

          <?php 

          } 
          }

          ?>

      </li>

</ul>

<script src="http://localhost/AlphaListNav.js"></script>
<script> const alphaNav = new AlphaListNav(document.getElementById('myList'));</script>
```

Output looks like this :

```
All │ 0-9 │ A │ B │ C │ D │ E │ F │ G │ H │ I │ J │ K │ L │ M │ N │ etc etc

A

A Day To Remember
A Killers Confession
A La Rock
A.K.A.
ACDC

B

Etc
```

I want to add a `count` (within the `li` element) at the end of each line for the number of records/rows for each `artists` from the `music` table.

Something like this..

```
A  

A Day To Remember (12)
A Killers Confession (4)
A La Rock (8)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems like your code will generate invalid HTML because you do not end the `<li>` tag within the while loop. This will result in a `<li>` tag for each row of the query result, but only 1 `</li>` at the very end, leaving `n-1` incomplete elements.

Comment: _"using the following code and it works fine"_ - a query with `ORDER BY ASC` at the end can absolutely not ever "work fine". This is missing _what_ you actually want to order by, and should get you nothing more than an _error_ from the database.

Comment: How about `SELECT artists, COUNT(*) as number_of_releases FROM music GROUP BY artists` instead of the DISTINCT query?

Comment: @CBroe - It does not return an error and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

GROUP BY is a key I suppose:

```
SELECT artist, COUNT(title) as music_count FROM music GROUP BY artist
```